# Mutually exclusive slot allocator for threads using a vector of slots and mutexes in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

If this has been posted anywhere else I am very sorry, but I could not find anything matching.

In a class we have found a pre-designed slot allocator which stores a specified number of slots that can be acquired by threads. If a slot is required, the slot should work, else it is blocked until another thread releases. The code looks like this:

```cpp
struct slot_allocator_mutexes
{
private:
    int num_slots = 8;
    vector<bool> slots;
    vector<mutex> mutexes;
public:
    slot_allocator_mutexes() : slots(num_slots, false), mutexes(num_slots) {}
    int acquire_slot()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < num_slots; ++i)
            {
                mutexes[i].lock();
                vector<bool>::reference slot_ref = slots[i];
                if (slot_ref == false)
                {
                    slot_ref = true;
                    mutexes[i].unlock();
                    return i;
                }
                mutexes[i].unlock();
            }
        }
    }
    void release_slot(int slot)
    {
        mutexes[slot].lock();
        assert(slots[slot] == true);
        slots[slot] = false;
        mutexes[slot].unlock();
    }
};
```

and will be called via

```cpp
    for (int t = 0; t < thread_numbers; ++t)
    {
        threads.push_back(thread([&]() {
            for (int r = 0; r < repeats; ++r)
            {
                int slot = alloc.acquire_slot();
                cout_lock.lock();
                cout << "iteration num: " << r << endl;
                cout << "Current slot: " << slot << " in thread number " << pthread_self() << endl;
                cout_lock.unlock();
                alloc.release_slot(slot);
            }
        }));
    }
```

Just to clarify: I know there might be cleaner implementations - this is not my question though.

My task was to find out if this is a correct thread-safe implementation of the allocator. Using the assert `assert(slots[slot] == true);` i soon found out, that something does not work. After doing research and multiple ways of testing this, I must admit I am out of ideas...

I do not get why this does not work. My initial thought was that the `mutexes[i].lock();` could be the fault, but since this is only a read operation this cannot really be the answer.

Thank you.

Comment: You don't appear to be giving us all the code. What is `m`? I see `m.unlock()`. Also you appear to name `mutexes` `locks` in the constructor. Please ensure your minimal reproducible example is free from these sorts of discrepancies, otherwise it's really just a guessing game

Comment: @Human-Compiler Very sorry for these mistakes, i changed some of the code and did not compilesince then. Should be working now

Comment: You still haven't posted a [mre]. Anyway, the answer is actually an *extremely* weird quirk of c++, and one I believe some of the c++ standard's authors very much regret nowadays. You will find the problem if you try to replace ugly explicit type names with `auto` and wonder why the compiler refuses the code.

Comment: @EOF I suppose you are talking about ``vector<bool>::reference slot_ref = slots[i];``? If i change that to auto it still compiles for me...?

Comment: But if you change that to `auto slot_ref = slots[i];`, you change the meaning, because `slot_ref` will not be a reference but a copy.

Comment: Sorry ... May i ask you to go into detail? I mean it is evident for me that this will be a copy then, but what does this knowledge change for me? I cannot really follow you

Comment: If you "@username" me, I get notified so I can respond faster. Anyway, replacing `vector<bool>::reference` with `auto` changes the semantics, but I just wanted you to change the syntax. If you only want to shorten and simplify the type, you could try `auto &`, which will leave `slot_ref` a reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::vector<bool>` is implemented effectively as a dynamic bitset. The exact way this is done is not specified by the standard, but will be implemented as a contiguous sequence of some integral type (e.g. `std::uint32_t`) where each bit represents a `bool` value in the `vector`.

As a result, setting any one value to `true` or `false` is actually modifying part of a larger object: the internal integer object. You can't simply lock on the singular bit that you are modifying and expect thread-safety, because more than one thread might be mutating that integer **at the same time.**

The only way to synchronize this correctly would be to not use a `vector<bool>` and instead use something like a `std::vector<std::uint8_t>` where each `uint8_t` is a unique object that can be independently locked and modified.

---

As a concrete example, imagine that the underlying int used in `vector<bool>` is a `uint32_t` -- so that you're operating on 32 bits at a time.

Now imagine that setting a bit is performed by these three operations:

1. Loading the integer value into a register
2. Performing the OR operation to set the bit to `1`, and
3. Storing the integer value back into memory

If the integer starts at value `0x0` (all bits set to zero), and we have two threads trying to set bits `0` and `1` at the same time, there *won't* be any locking by the mutex, because each bit has a separate mutex. Instead, what we may see, is the following race condition:

```
 Thread 1                    Thread 2
 Lock mutex for bit 0
                             Lock mutex for bit 1
 Load <int> into register  
                             Load same <int> into register
 OR 0x1 with the register
                             OR 0x2 with the register
 Write register back to mem
                             Write register back to mem
 Unlock mutex for bit 0
                             unlock mutex for bit 1
```

Note that thread 2 will **clobber** the value of thread 1 in this scenario. Formally, this is actually just **undefined behavior** and whatever we see at this point is completely undefined by the standard. We could see `0x1`, we could see `0x2`, or we could see `0x3` if things were sequenced correctly. Technically with undefined behavior, anything is possible.

Comment: Wow, perfect answer! Thank you so much... That is honestly a pretty dumb optimization. As a user i would expect every element of a vector to be an individual type...

Comment: The `vector<bool>` specialization is definitely one of the more controversial and much regretted design decisions in the standard library. Unfortunately it's unlikely to really change much, to avoid breaking backwards-compatibility... By the way, If this answers your question, please make sure to mark it as the solution! :)

Answer (score 0):

How about using just one mutex and a [condition variable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable)? Please see the examples in cppreference and consider redesigning your solution.

Comment: As mentioned, my goal is not to achieve another correct implementation but to understand why this is not thread-safe